# Email validation flash message not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

My error checking message seems to be having trouble. All I have are 3 fields in a controller for a contact us form that emails the owner of the site (via gmail smtp). One being a the person's email, subject and message. All I'm really checking is if the fields are blank and if the user type's in a valid email. The validation checking seems to be working fine and does not send an email respectively. However, my error flash message won't prompt a message what exactly went wrong. Here's what my about controller looks like:

```
class AboutController < ApplicationController
# ...\controllers\home_controller.rb
#----------------------------------------------------
# show contact form

def contact
@title = "Contact"
@sender = ''
@subject = ''
@message = ''
end

def sendmail
@sender = params[:sender]
@subject = params[:subject]
@message = params[:message]
if validate(@sender, @subject, @message)
  UserEmail.contact(@sender, @subject, @message).deliver      
  flash[:success] = "Your message sent sucessfully!"      **//This message works**
  redirect_to about_index_path
else

flash.now[:error] = "Your message did not send, please make sure all fields are 

appropriately filled out." **//This message does not.** 

  redirect_to about_index_path
end
end

private
def validate(sender, subject, message)
  @email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  if sender.blank? || subject.blank? || message.blank?

    return false
elsif sender[@email_regex].nil?

    return false
  else
    return true
  end
end
end
```

Application_html.erb

```
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>

<div class="alert <%= flash_class type %>">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
    <%= message %>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `flash.now` for the one that isn't working despite that being a redirect.

Comment: boom. thanks, I think it's time for new glasses. ;-)